# Spring 5 - Read JSON or MultipartFile

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

I ran into what looks like a really simple problem. I have an http endpoint which should accept either JSON body or uploaded file.

Here is definition of controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/endpoint")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> createResource(
       @RequestParam(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
       @RequestBody(required = false) Command command){
}
```

Command is a POJO class with Jackson annotations for deserialisation.
When I pass JSON body with *`Content-Type: application/json`*, it works fine. But when I pass file with *`Content-Type: multipart/form-data`*, I get 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Here is raw http request when passing just JSON body.

```
POST /api/devices?= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
{"foo": "bar"}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Any ideas what is causing this, thanks.

Comment: just to make sure, have you configured org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/endpoint",consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> createResource(
       @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
       @RequestPart Command command){
}
```

Comment: Now I dont get 415, but command variable is null when i pass json.

Comment: Please share the Post request you are are using to test

Comment: Updated post. And btw. when I remove required = false. Spring throws Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet

Comment: Your post request is incorrect . Content-Type cannot be application/json. Your post request should be some what like 
POST http://localhost:8080/api/endpoint
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="abc.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

< ./abc.csv

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Comment: Why it can not be application/json if I am posting JSON body?

Comment: required = false means these fields are optional. Change it accordingly is you want the field to be optional

Comment: Since you are using Multipart along with RequestBody hence Content-Type: multipart/form-data should be used

Answer (score 0):

You might need two separate methods with different parameters and annotations. Which, of course, can each just call a shared internal method for their common behaviors.